# API testing using postman

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest, postman

I am developing Rest APIs for some project and testing them using postman to send the data on my mLab server. But All I could get:

```
{
 "error": {
        "message": "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\periodical API\\uploads\\2018-06-16T14:34:38.384Zhd-wallpaper-of-live.jpg'"

    }
}
```

Here's my route code:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Product = require("../models/product");


exports.products_get_all = (req, res, next) => 
{
  Product.find()
    .select("name price quantity date subject _id productImage")
    .exec()
    .then(docs => {
      const response = {
        count: docs.length,
        products: docs.map(doc => {
          return {
            name: doc.name,
            price: doc.price,
            quantity: doc.quantity,
            date: doc.date,
            subject: doc.subject,
            productImage: doc.productImage,
            _id: doc._id,
            request: {
              type: "GET",
              url: "http://localhost:3000/products/" + doc._id
            }
          };
        })
      };

      res.status(200).json(response);

    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
};

exports.products_create_product = (req, res, next) => {
  const product = new Product({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    name: req.body.name,
    price: req.body.price,
    quantity: req.body.quantity,
    date: req.body.date,
    subject: req.body.subject,
    productImage: req.file.path
  });
  product
    .save()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(201).json({
        message: "Created product successfully",
        createdProduct: {
          name: result.name,
          price: result.price,
          quantity: result.quantity,
          date: result.date,
          subject: result.subject,
          _id: result._id,
          request: {
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:3000/products/" + result._id
          }
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
};

exports.products_get_product = (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.productId;
  Product.findById(id)
    .select("name price quantity date subject _id productImage")
    .exec()
    .then(doc => {
      console.log("From database", doc);
      if (doc) {
        res.status(200).json({
          product: doc,
          request: {
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:3000/products"
          }
        });
      } else {
        res
          .status(404)
          .json({ message: "No valid entry found for provided ID" });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: err });
    });
};

exports.products_update_product = (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.productId;
  const updateOps = {};
  for (const ops of req.body) {
    updateOps[ops.propName] = ops.value;
  }
  Product.update({ _id: id }, { $set: updateOps })
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "Product updated",
        request: {
          type: "GET",
          url: "http://localhost:3000/products/" + id
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
};

exports.products_delete = (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.productId;
  Product.remove({ _id: id })
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "Product deleted",
        request: {
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost:3000/products",
          body: { name: "String", price: "Number" }
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
};
```

I myself could not figure out the problem as I am a bit newbie on developing APIs.

Comment: @Ashish can you please elaborate on that, as I have tried other possible ways to define the path for the file.

Comment: I am quite clear about both the path types. and that .jpg file, i am uploading it on the server. So no issue regarding it's path. I have tried same things on different machine before and it worked fine. But now stuck as performing on different machine.

Comment: You need to first visit here [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

On Linux servers  ENOENT  means

> “No such file or directory”

said that the response you are getting is trying to let you know that,

1. The directory where you are trying to save, does not exist
2. The place of file you are looking for does not exist.

What I do recommend you is that you use your debugger tool to stop the execution before you try to get to the directory or where you try to read your file. That way you will understand where your code is failing.

Now many times when I get to this error, usually means that the directory does not exist but more frequently that you do no have permission to save the file.

Good luck, I hope it helps.

http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html